# República Checa ou Chéquia?

Tags: nomes

República Checa ou Chéquia? Oiço das duas formas, qual é a mais correta?

Comment: @Lambie "The Czech government approved *Czechia* as the official English short name in 2016. The short name has been listed by the United Nations and is used by other organizations such as the European Union, the CIA, and Google Maps." Please see [Adoption of *Czechia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_the_Czech_Republic#Adoption_of_Czechia) e [Chéquia ou Tchéquia (em checo, *Česko*, pronunciado: ［ˈtʃɛsko］, *Česká republika*［ˈt͡ʃɛskaː ˈrɛpuˌblɪka］é um país da Europa Central...](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A9quia) também.

Comment: @tchrist Chéquia ou Tchéquia[3][4][5] (em checo, Česko, pronunciado: [ˈtʃɛsko])[nota 1], **oficialmente República Checa ou Tcheca** (em tcheco/checo: Česká republika, pronunciado: [ˈt͡ʃɛskaː ˈrɛpuˌblɪka] (Sobre este somescutar (ajuda·info))) é um país da Europa Central, https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chéquia

Comment: @Lambie I was having trouble with the formatting and lost that bit via a spurious deletion to try to get rid of the bracketed footnotes. Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist Well, I'm glad we ironed that out. Did you ever see the post where I asked for you help? You never answered me. [I will delete this later.]

Comment: Olá mods. Uma pergunta pode ser específica a pt-PT, ou específica a pt-BR. Não acho que possa geralmente ser das duas tags... (exceto casos incomuns como por exemplo para discutir coisas como [tag:diferenças-transatlânticas]). CIMend parece botar sempre as duas tags, mas eu fartei-me de comentar e corrigir isso. ‍♀️ É a vossa vez, se acharem correto.

Comment: centro da europa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ambos estão corretos.
[Em 2016](https://www.dn.pt/mundo/republica-checa-vai-ter-outro-nome-5128009.html), a *República Checa* aprovou em parlamento a adoção de um nome abreviado para o país - que, em português europeu*, é [*Chéquia*](https://european-union.europa.eu/principles-countries-history/country-profiles/czechia_pt) (em inglês, *Czechia*). Desde então que ambos os nomes podem ser utilizados.

*Em português brasileiro, ambos os nomes se escrevem com *T* - ou seja, usa-se *Tchéquia* ou *República Tcheca*.

O uso de um ou outro termo continua a ser um tópico divisivo entre os checos ([What’s in a name? Understanding the Czech Republic vs. Czechia debate](https://kafkadesk.org/2020/03/31/whats-in-a-name-understanding-the-czech-republic-vs-czechia-debate/))
mas existem várias motivações para a mudança (para além da praticalidade, existe a questão de a República Checa ou Chéquia continuar a ser reconhecida internacionalmente como Checoslováquia).

Comment: ["não cabe nas camisolas de desporto"](https://www.dn.pt/mundo/republica-checa-vai-ter-outro-nome-5128009.html) :)

Comment: Fico com a dúvida se haverá um nome preferencial, do ponto de vista dos "checos". Pelo site europeu imagino que sim, mas esta resposta não esclarece isso; acho que ficava melhor ainda se clarificasse esse ponto - se há um nome preferencial.

Comment: Entre os checos, o tema é ainda divisivo. Deixo um link para um artigo de 2020 que explora bastante bem a questão